# Javascript, работающий без присутствия

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт, сейчас работающий в tampermonkey, что неудобно, приходится держать страницу постоянно открытой, нужно чтобы он работал на сайте 24 часа в сутки без моего присутствия. Слышал что-то про осуществление с помощью google apps script, но похоже гугл выложил туториалы для работы только со своими сервисами. Собственно, сабж.

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы пользовательский скрипт работал, когда вы страницей не пользуетесь?

Это точно нужно?

Comment: Да, чтобы скрипт без моего зоркого глаза осуществлял поставленную задачу. Все зависит от сложности исполнения и побочных эффектов.

Comment: Страницу скорее всего придется держать открытой или изучать взаимодействие посредством get/post запросов. Бота для какой-то браузерной игры делаете?

Comment: Нет, простой скрипт для выполнения задачи новичка - клацающий нужные кнопки не без выгоды для меня конечно же:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подобного на данный момент не существует. Нужно неимоверное кол-во хаков и в итоге что-нибудь, как эмулятор браузера, всё равно будет открыто. В 2014 EcmaScript планируют решить этот вопрос. Технология [Service Worker](http://video.yandex.ru/users/ya-events/view/2209).

Comment: кстати, в chrome://flags можно уже включить эти service worker. попробуйте.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял задачу, то вы можете воспользоваться http://phantomjs.org/ для эмуляции браузера и через него клацать на кнопки на странице.

Т.е. по сути у вас в консоле будет запущенна эмуляция браузера, которая сама будет заходить на страничку и жать на кнопку.

Comment: Спасибо, это мне пригодится. Имел ввиду я немного другое, но и это поможет, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Есть *Selenium web driver* , с тихим драйвером(без вывода браузера). Простой и понятный API позволяет эмулировать работу с браузером, бибилотека доступна на многих языках разработки. Cегодня завтра - это будет **стандартом** работы с браузерами.

Он включает в себя нужный вам *Java script executor*